# Determine size of files in zip?

Tags: ios

To keep total size of my app down, I would like to distribute some very large databases as ZIP files, then unpack them as needed. Is there an easy way to determine the size of a file in a ZIP so I know in advance if there is space on the device to even try to unzip one of them?

The ZIP file would contain only one file. Yes, I could measure the size in advance and hardcode it, but that's error prone, as I update the databases on a regular basis.

Best regards,
  Anders

Comment: @MartinSerrano How does a question related to extracting files from a zip in Java relate to determining the size of a file in a zip in an iOS app?

Comment: @rmaddy, my bad, i thought this was a java question.  wrong tag.  sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few 3rd party Objective-C libraries for working with ZIP files. These would allow you to interrogate the contents of a zip file without needing to unzip them first.

Check out [ZipKit](https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home) or [Objective-Zip](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/).

Comment: OK, I see that Objective-Zip will do it. I was looking at https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive but that only zips and unzips files - otherwise looks like just what I need, no more no less.

Comment: ...and on closer inspection, ssziparchive will send a message to the delegate with the relevant info as well :) Shoulda made me a test app first :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [zipzap](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap) like this:

```
NSUInteger wantedFileSize = NSNotFound;
ZZArchive* archive = [ZZArchive archiveWithURL:zipFileURL error:nil];
for (ZZArchiveEntry entry in archive.entries)
  if ([entry.fileName isEqualToString:wantedFileName])
  {
     wantedFileSize = entry.uncompressedSize;
     break;
  }
```

This will be fast since it only scans the last blocks of the zip file for the uncompressed size of the entry you want, and doesn't do any decompression.